# unexpected end of file error in shell script

Tags: bash

**hi, I'm new in learning scripts and when i try to run the following scripts i get these errors**:

```
./snortscript.sh: line 168: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
./snortscript.sh: line 173: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

**this happens when i try to run a script in order to run snort service in centos 7**

---

and heres the script

### the error occurs in lines 168 and 172

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# snort  Start up the SNORT Intrusion Detection System daemon
#
# chkconfig: 2345 55 25
# description: SNORT is a Open Source Intrusion Detection System
#This service starts up the snort daemon.
#
# processname: snort
# pidfile: /var/run/snort_eth0.pid
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: snort
# Required-Start: $local_fs $network $syslog
# Required-Stop: $local_fs $syslog
# Should-Start: $syslog
# Should-Stop: $network $syslog
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start up the SNORT Intrusion Detection System daemon
# Description:
#SNORT is an application for Open Source Intrusion Detection.
#
#This service starts up the Snort IDS daemon.
### END INIT INFO
# source function library
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions
# pull in sysconfig settings
[ -f /etc/sysconfig/snort ] && . /etc/sysconfig/snort
RETVAL=0
prog="snort"
lockfile=/var/lock/subsys/$prog
# Some functions to make the below more readable
SNORTD=/usr/local/bin/snort
#OPTIONS="-A fast -b -d -D -i eth0 -u snort -g snort -c /etc/snort/snort.conf -l
/var/log/snort"
#PID_FILE=/var/run/snort_eth0.pid
# Convert the /etc/sysconfig/snort settings to something snort can
# use on the startup line.if [ "$ALERTMODE"X = "X" ]; then
ALERTMODE=""
else
ALERTMODE="-A $ALERTMODE"
fi
if [ "$USER"X = "X" ]; then
USER="snort"
fi
if [ "$GROUP"X = "X" ]; then
GROUP="snort"
fi
if [ "$BINARY_LOG"X = "1X" ]; then
BINARY_LOG="-b"
else
BINARY_LOG=""
fi
if [ "$LINK_LAYER"X = "1X" ]; then
LINK_LAYER="-e"
else
LINK_LAYER=""
fi
if [ "$CONF"X = "X" ]; then
CONF="-c /etc/snort/snort.conf"
else
CONF="-c $CONF"
fi
if [ "$INTERFACE"X = "X" ]; then
INTERFACE="-i eth0"
PID_FILE="/var/run/snort_eth0.pid"
else
PID_FILE="/var/run/snort_$INTERFACE.pid"
INTERFACE="-i $INTERFACE"
fi
if [ "$DUMP_APP"X = "1X" ]; then
DUMP_APP="-d"
else
DUMP_APP=""
fiif [ "$NO_PACKET_LOG"X = "1X" ]; then
NO_PACKET_LOG="-N"
else
NO_PACKET_LOG=""
fi
if [ "$PRINT_INTERFACE"X = "1X" ]; then
PRINT_INTERFACE="-I"
else
PRINT_INTERFACE=""
fi
if [ "$PASS_FIRST"X = "1X" ]; then
PASS_FIRST="-o"
else
PASS_FIRST=""
fi
if [ "$LOGDIR"X = "X" ]; then
LOGDIR=/var/log/snort
fi
# These are used by the 'stats' option
if [ "$SYSLOG"X = "X" ]; then
SYSLOG=/var/log/messages
fi
if [ "$SECS"X = "X" ]; then
SECS=5
fi
if [ ! "$BPFFILE"X = "X" ]; then
BPFFILE="-F $BPFFILE"
fi
runlevel=$(set -- $(runlevel); eval "echo \$$#" )
start()
{
[ -x $SNORTD ] || exit 5
echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
daemon --pidfile=$PID_FILE $SNORTD $ALERTMODE $BINARY_LOG
$LINK_LAYER $NO_PACKET_LOG $DUMP_APP -D $PRINT_INTERFACE$INTERFACE -u $USER -g $GROUP $CONF -l $LOGDIR $PASS_FIRST $BPFFILE
$BPF && success || failure
RETVAL=$?
[ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && touch $lockfile
echo
return $RETVAL
}
stop()
{
echo -n $"Stopping $prog: "
killproc $SNORTD
if [ -e $PID_FILE ]; then
chown -R $USER:$GROUP $PID_FILE &&
rm -f $PID_FILE
fi
RETVAL=$?
# if we are in halt or reboot runlevel kill all running sessions
# so the TCP connections are closed cleanly
if [ "x$runlevel" = x0 -o "x$runlevel" = x6 ] ; then
trap '' TERM
killall $prog 2>/dev/null
trap TERM
fi
[ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && rm -f $lockfile
echo
return $RETVAL
}
restart() {
stop
start
}
rh_status() {
status -p $PID_FILE $SNORTD
}
rh_status_q() {
rh_status >/dev/null 2>&1
}
case "$1" in
start)
rh_status_q && exit 0start
;;
stop)
if ! rh_status_q; then
rm -f $lockfile
exit 0
fi
stop
;;
restart)
restart
;;
status)
       rh_status
       RETVAL=$?
       if [ $RETVAL -eq 3 -a -f $lockfile ] ; then
       RETVAL=2
       fi
;;
*)
echo $"Usage: $0{start|stop|restart|status}"
RETVAL=2
esac    
exit $RETVAL
```

Comment: You have an unmatched `"`, always run your code through [**shellcheck.net**](http://www.shellcheck.net/) first, then if you still have problems, ask here.

Comment: The problem is the line `/var/log/snort"`.  As David says, though, use shellcheck first.  I am voting to close as a typo.

Comment: [Indent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, see `line 34 and 35`

```
#OPTIONS="-A fast -b -d -D -i eth0 -u snort -g snort -c /etc/snort/snort.conf -l
/var/log/snort"
```

The comment starts at line 34, but there is a newline at 35. So you should write it as:

```
#OPTIONS="-A fast -b -d -D -i eth0 -u snort -g snort -c /etc/snort/snort.conf -l /var/log/snort"
```

in one single line. That should fix the error you are getting. Notice how in the question you asked, the syntax highlighting is messed up. That will be clear too.

There are two more errors in the script. One is in `line 38`, where you have to break a new line just before the `if` starts, at `... startup line.if [ "$ALERTMODE"X = "X" ];...`, corrected code for which should be:

```
# use on the startup line
if [ "$ALERTMODE"X = "X" ]; then
ALERTMODE=""
...
```

Another is at `line 75`, where we have `fiif [ "$NO_PACKET_LOG"X = "1X" ]; then`, which should be:

```
fi
if [ "$NO_PACKET_LOG"X = "1X" ]; then
```

line break again. Seems like the script was not copied properly from the source, so the formatting was messed up.

Answer (score 0):

The error is the wrong usage-hint in **line 168**. Correct it to:

```
echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|status}"
```